# how to return full table data bu using function in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to  return the multiple records in table but do not know how. To return all values of table and return ?

please tell how can i do it.

```
function get_semester_data($id) {         
      $query_1="SELECT sem.smstr_id,sem.smstr_no,sem.start_mnth,sem.start_year,sem.end_mnth,sem.end_year,sem.status FROM `semesters` sem,sessions s where s.s_id=sem.s_id and s.s_id=$id";
      $result=mysql_query($query_1);
      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  



      }

      return $row;       
}
```

i want to  return the multiple records in table but do not know how. to return all values of table and return ?

please tell how can i do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return an array of rows!

```
function get_semester_data($id) {         
  $query_1="SELECT sem.smstr_id,sem.smstr_no,sem.start_mnth,sem.start_year,sem.end_mnth,sem.end_year,sem.status FROM `semesters` sem,sessions s where s.s_id=sem.s_id and s.s_id=$id";
  $result=mysql_query($query_1);
  $all_rows = array();
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
     $all_rows[] = $row;
  }

  return $all_rows;       
}

//Get the values like this
$rows = get_semester_data(12);

//print all smstr_no like this
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo $row[1];
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Please accept and upvote if it answered your question :)

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){  
      $data[]=$row;
}                       
return $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

First the code:

```
function get_semester_data($id) {         
  $query_1="SELECT sem.smstr_id,sem.smstr_no,sem.start_mnth,sem.start_year,sem.end_mnth,sem.end_year,sem.status FROM `semesters` sem,sessions s where s.s_id=sem.s_id and s.s_id=$id";
  $result=mysql_query($query_1);
  $result = array();
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
  array_push($result, $row); 
  }

  return $result;       
}
```

Just declare the array, add the rows and return it.
Suggestions:

- the extension you are using is old and will be deprecated, use mysqli
  or pdo instead
- be careful and sanitize your input because you are prone to SQL
  Injection on the $id parameter. Use this:

`$query_1="SELECT  sem.smstr_id, sem.smstr_no, sem.start_mnth, sem.start_year, sem.end_mnth, sem.end_year, sem.status FROM semesters sem,sessions s where s.s_id=sem.s_id and s.s_id = '" . htmlentities($id, ENT_QUOTES) . "'";`